# Utilização do Uniq

Tags: linux, regex, shell-script

Andei pesquisando sem muito sucesso, algo que na teoria acredito ser bem simples, porem não encontrei o comando correto.

Tenho um arquivo de LOG com varias informações, porem certas informações se repetem, porem apenas em uma determinada coluna, e tudo que se repetir nesta coluna, queria que fosse eliminado, permanecendo apenas uma. Exemplo:

```
  6; Mar 21 03:18; 182.69.170.145;  unknown;  <alfredo.xxx@xxx.com.br>;  Get much more positive aspects out of your work out; HIGH
  3; Mar 21 03:20; 182.69.170.145;  unknown;  <alfredo.xxx@xxx.com.br>;  Eating healthful is not assisting you lose weight; HIGH
  2; Mar 21 03:18; 182.69.170.145;  unknown;  <alfredo.xxx@xxx.com.br>;  Asian infused diet program pill makes it was West; MEDIUM
  2; Mar 21 13:50; 201.53.117.127;  unknown;  <albino_xxx@xxx.com.br>;  want to see me?; MEDIUM
  3; Mar 21 12:28; 179.208.77.183;  unknown;  <albino_xxx@xxx.com.br>;  how do you like it here?; HIGH
  3; Mar 21 13:49; 201.53.117.127;  unknown;  <albino_xxx@xxx.com.br>;  Good Evening How are things? I m Yana; HIGH
```

Percebem que o campo e-mail se repete, porem após ele não, sendo assim, utilizar o SORT com UNIQ não resolveria meu problema, logo que eles ordenam e eliminam a linha exatamente igual.

Existe algum comando, ou até estes mesmos (SORT e UNIQ) com algum parâmetro especifico que faça isso?

Grato.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer, tem como colocar um exemplo dos dados de como você deseja que fique?

Comment: Usando os dados acima, necessito que apenas a coluna que contem o e-mail <alfredo.xxx> seja utilizada pelo uniq, eliminando os repetidos. Perceba que a linha é toda diferente, exceto a coluna e-mail, então dando um uniq nesta coluna, deixará apenas uma linha no filtro. Se eu der um uniq no arquivo que contém os dados acima, eliminará a linha que estiver 100% igual, porem nunca será totalmente igual.

Comment: Podias indicar qual a saída pretendida para este exemplo?

Comment: Na saída acima temos 6 linhas de LOG, o que eu queria é a saída ter apenas uma linha de LOG, pois eu não preciso de 6 linhas do e-mail <alfredo.xxx@>, se dentro de um arquivo de LOG tiver mil linhas, e dentre estas mil linhas, tiver 100 linhas sob o e-mail <alfredo.xxx@>, como o UNIQ remove os repetidos, queria que removesse todos os repetidos da coluna e-mail, deixando apenas uma. Se eu setar o UNIQ sem direcionar a coluna, ele vai eliminar a linha exatamente igual, e veja que nas 6 linhas acima, apenas a conta de e-mail é igual, o restante não é. Queria usar o campo e-mail como delimitador.

Comment: Você quer agrupar somente os emails alfredo.xxx? ou quer agrupar todos os repetidos?

Comment: Para o exemplo acima, gostaria de ter apenas uma linha de e-mail completo, com (data/hora IP e etc) e o restante ser eliminado. Pois, no LOG terei 100 mil linhas com diversos e-mails repetidos, porem o restante não se repete, como IP, Data/Hora e Subject. Queria que dessa massa de dados eliminar apenas as linhas que se repetem os e-mails, permanecendo apenas uma.

Comment: @user54154 tenta esse comando então: `sort -u -t ';' -k5,5 nome-do-arquivo`, aqui funcionou direitinho. OBS.: Substitua nome-do-arquivo pelo arquivo de LOG.

Comment: Deu certo :), pode me explicar o parâmetro? Para eu saber o que exatamente ele faz para eu aprender? Grato.

Comment: Vou colocar uma resposta explicando cada coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar esse comando:

```
sort -u -t ';' -k5,5 nome-do-arquivo
```

- `-u` (unique) o que faz os valores iguais serem agrupados.
- `-t ';'` Define o separador das colunas (que no caso do seu arquivo é o `;`).
- `-k5,5` Define o número da coluna que você quer trabalhar (no seu caso 5, que é o email, e somente ele).

Você pode ler mais sobre o comando `sort` [aqui](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html).

Comment: E qual o parâmetro que elimina os repetidos, pois o "u" só agrupa. Muito obrigado.

Comment: O proprio -u que faz a remoção dos repetidos. Acabei de testar aqui. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Exatamente @user54154 quando ele agrupa ele elimina tudo.

Answer (score 1):

Já agora, se for importante manter a ordem do ficheiro original,
podes:

```
awk -F';' '++n[$5] == 1' nome
```

- `-F ';'` -- define o FieldSeparator (separador de campo)
- `n[$5]` -- conta o número de ocorrências de cada valor do campo 5 (email) ; O vector `n` tem índices do tipo string (array associativo)
- `++n[$5]` -- incrementa o valor correspondente ao email específico
- `++n[$5] == 1` -- primeira ocorrência desse email (acão por omissão: `print`)

Comment: Muito bom. Pode explicar os parâmetros também? Acredito que o -F é o delimitador, o ==1 deve ser o retorno de apenas uma linha,  o '++[$5], deve ser a 5º coluna, mas n entendi o ++n. Grato.